# atmel studio for mac

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmel, gcc

Is Atmel Studio compatible with Mac or Linux?

It seems like there is only Windows support from the downlaods here: http://www.microchip.com/mplab/avr-support/atmel-studio-7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, recent versions of Atmel studio are based on Visual Studio which is Windows only.

You could run it in a virtual machine.

But it's worth noting that Atmel studio uses avr-gcc and arm-none-eabi-gcc (and presumably an avr32 gcc) to do the actual compilation, all of which are available for other platforms.  As are downloading tools for their bootloaders, and ISP and SWD/JTAG tools like avrdude, OpenOCD, etc.

Also the Atmel Software Framework of chip-specific source code libraries is available as a huge zip file download independent of Atmel studio.

GDB works well with an SWD adapter for Atmel's ARM parts, there are some indications it can be made to work with the AVRs connected via an Atmel ICE, but never personally tried that.

So unless you want to use a setup that's unique to Atmel parts, you can readily target their parts using your favorite work environment running on top of your favorite operating system.

Comment: "recent versions of Atmel studio are based on Visual Studio ***which is Windows only.***" That's not entirely true. I use Platformio for code editing and its based on Visual Studio Code which runs on both Mac and Windows. Thus; if Atmel Studio could run in Visual Stduio code then it would be possible to run it on either platform (and likely Linux too)

Comment: @BrynParrott , *"Visual Studio"* & *"Visual Studio Code"* are different IDEs. Atmel Studio is based on VS, not VSCode. And Atmel Studio doesn't run *in* VSCode, the compiler is run *by* VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

[Later 4.x versions seem to work in wine](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=402), but most people programming for AVR µCs on Linux don't use Atmel Studio anyway but command line avr-gcc, Makefiles and a decent text editor. (Or eclipse.)

Comment: I am looking for a front end debugger to use with the atmel ice. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JoeyGough - I haven't tried it, but eclipse apparently has support for debugging AVR targets.  See [documentation here](http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Debugging).

Comment: This isn't about eclipse, but about AVaRICE. It's a remote debugging adapter to gdb, so you can use any Linux debugging GUI with it.